# Vector of enum values creates ownership issues

Tags: rust, ownership

I have two fragments of code which worked well until a few days ago. They look fairly simple:

1.

```
let mut mask = 0 as c_ulong;
for bit in bits.iter() {
    mask |= *bit as c_ulong;
}
```

2.

```
for bit in vec!(...).iter() {
    if res & *bit as c_ulong != 0 {
        bits.push(*bit);
    }
}
```

The vector iterated vector in both cases contains an `enum` like:

```
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
#[deriving(PartialEq,Show)]
pub enum SomeEnum {
    BLAH                 = 0x01,
    ...
}
```

But unfortunately now that code causes the following error on all `*bit` expressions.

```
cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
```

I don't understand this error. Why is it now not allowed? I have a pointer to an immutable vector with enum variants that are practically just `int` values.

Also, how can I fix it? I know the first case can be transformed to use `.into_iter()` - that's ok, I don't need that vector afterwards. But in the second fragment, I actually can't use `bit` twice after `.into_iter()`. Even though I only compare it the first time!

Am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type used to be `Copy`, but [this trait is now opt-in](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17864).

Add `#[deriving(Clone, Copy)]` (or add `Clone` and `Copy` to the list of traits in an existing `#[deriving]` attribute) to your type. You need to implement both `Clone` and `Copy`, because [`Copy` is a subtrait of `Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) (as any type that implements `Copy` can also trivially implement `Clone`).

```rust
pub trait Copy: Clone { }
```

Comment: Ah nice, I did not know it had finally come to pass.

Comment: In `1.0` it's `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` now. Every `Copy` type also has to implement `Clone`.